# How to check pricing tier for credits and storage for the current account in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, snowflake-task

I want to write a SQL query that gives me any sort of information related to the current pricing for credits and storage of my current account. Any alternate solution is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Last I checked with our Snowflake rep, there is currently no way to query your credit costs from the Snowflake interface. That information is only available in your contract details, or from your rep.

I found this [dbt package](https://about.gitlab.com/blog/2020/04/08/snowflake-spend-dbt-package-release/) very helpful for monitoring this stuff. It allows you to upload your credit pricing as a CSV and it extrapolates out the costs for you from there.